# configure zsh highlight for unknown command type

Tags: zsh

I have currently set up my ZSH highlighting like this:

```
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS=(main brackets pattern line)
typeset -A ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES # For main-highlighter
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command]='fg=blue'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[function]='fg=green'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[builtin]='fg=red'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[unknown]='fg=green,bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[arg0]='fg=white'
```

I wanted to add a directive, so that a command word, which is not a valid command (i.e. not in the PATH, nor a function or alias; i.e. a word *w*, for which `type w` would print *w not found*) is shown in a different colour, so that I can already find typing errors while typing the comman line.

Example: If I want to type `gawk`, but start typing the command

```
gwk ...
```

instead (and gwk is not a valid command in my environment), I would like to see it a different colour, so that I am alerted of the typing mistake early.

I first thought that the style named *arg0* would handle this, but obviously it does not.

Is this possible to achieve, and which highlight style would I have to use for this?

Comment: I’m not sure what you want to achieve. I think you left out some words in that long sentence in the middle. Can you try splitting it up into smaller chunks?

Comment: @MarlonRichert: You are right. I fixed it, and added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `unknown-token`: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/master/docs/highlighters/main.md

---

PS: I maintain a [Zsh plugin called Z Colors](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zcolors) that can convert your `$LS_COLORS` to `zsh-syntax-highlighting`. It takes care of that stuff automatically.